# Can't convert an image's bytes into a stream

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

So basically I'm trying to get the image's bytes from an URL. This seems to work, now I need to convert it to stream so I can send it through Discord.

```cs
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
   var imageContent = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(response.Url);
            
   using (var imageBuffer = new MemoryStream(imageContent))
   {
      await new DiscordMessageBuilder().AddFile("image.png", imageBuffer, false).SendAsync(commandContext.Channel);
   }
}
```

But this throw me the follow exception when trying `new MemoryStream(imageContent);`

> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream. at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout();

Any idea? Also, it seems the AddFiles method only accepts FileStream, can I send it a Stream without having the file itself saved on my storage?

[image]

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the exception type, message, **full** traceback, and inner exceptions if any?  Because it is very hard to believe that the `new MemoryStream(byte [])` constructor is throwing the exception shown.

Comment: Error messages when you look at an object in the debugger are not exceptions.

Comment: Also mind that you shouldn't be `using` HttpClient.

Comment: What is `DiscordMessageBuilder`?  Is it [`DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordMessageBuilder`](https://dsharpplus.github.io/DSharpPlus/api/DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordMessageBuilder.html)?  If you were to [edit] your question and [tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) it with the library you're using (probably [tag:dsharp+]), you're more likely to attract someone who can answer.  See [ask].

Comment: I don't know, but at a quick glance, it looks like you've consumed the `imageBuffer` stream twice.  ("buffer" is a bad name for a "stream", btw)  Once with `Image.FromStream(imageBuffer)` and then again by passing it to `AddFile("image.png", imageBuffer, false)`.  Perhaps the stream's position would need to be reset if you intend to read it twice.

Comment: Building on the comment of @Wyck, what are you using `image` for after you do `var image = Image.FromStream(imageBuffer);`?  Because you are not passing it to `DiscordMessageBuilder`.  Building an image from a stream requires time and memory, if you don't need it I suggest you don't do it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply!, there's no inner exceptions, also yeah, I'm using DSharpPlus nuget. Regardless the Image.FromStream() forget that line, I was just testing and forgot to remove that line. I've updated my post with the info that has imageBuffer.

Comment: @Wyck It's exactly this. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Fildor yo, weird cuestion, haha. Should I not use HttpClient or should I not use "using" in HttpClient?

Comment: @Martaflorescalvo _"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application."_ - [Supplemental API remarks - HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-net-http-httpclient#instancing)